# FLUTTER | Custom Circular Progress Indicator

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

How can I make a custom circular progress indicator like the ones in the below image in Flutter? The out of box one does not allow adding text in the center.

[Screenshot of Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7Kn3.png)

Comment: try to create your own , follow http://cogitas.net/custom-loading-animation-flutter/

Comment: This shows a basic with animations,  I am actually confused at the part at how to display the progress. Other than that I just have to put circle shapes in a stack widget and I will get a circle bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have two ways.

first put `CircularProgressIndicator` and `Text` widgets into `Stack` and place them as you want(`Text` in the center and `CircularProgressIndicator` cover all stack space). `Stack` widget is key point here for you to understand...

the second way and more flexible way is to this action with `CustomPaint` Widget.
this link will help you to achieve the goal...
https://medium.com/@NPKompleet/creating-an-analog-clock-in-flutter-i-68def107d9f4

Comment: Also take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svxUUz5mi9s for ideas how to do custom painting.

Comment: Also, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45130497/creating-a-custom-clock-widget-in-flutter/45133660#45133660

Comment: I tried using the stack widget but the amounts I have are too big and are escaping the circles, any way I can increase the size of the indcators