# How can I use the Skia API in a Flutter widget?

Tags: flutter, skia

I want to use Skia API directly in my widget for drawing. How do I create a Skia widget?

Or is there any reason why I shouldn't do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few starting points:

- https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-what-are-widgets-renderobjects-and-elements-630a57d05208
- [Creating a custom clock widget in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45130497/creating-a-custom-clock-widget-in-flutter/45133660)
- https://www.raywenderlich.com/4562681-flutter-text-rendering